# Set value from class B and get the value from class C. Class B and class C are Subclass of Class A

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism, subclass

I've a class `MessageStorage` and it's been subclassed into 2 classes `MessageSent` and `MessageReceive`. I've defined a `NSString` property in `MessageStorage` class. Now I want to set this string property from `MessageSent` class and get the string from `MessageReceive` class. 

How can I achieve this?

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {    // SuperClass MessageStorage

    if (!messageStorage) {
        messageStorage = [[MessageStorage alloc] init];
    }

    return messageStorage;
}

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {    // SubClass of MessageStorage

    if (!msSend) {  
        msSend = [[MSSend alloc] init];
    }

    return msSend;
}


+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {     // SubClass of MessageStorage

    if (!msReceive) {
        msReceive = [[MSReceive alloc] init];
    }

    return msReceive;
}
```

I guess I'm not setting the `sharedInstance` properly. 
What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Creating a ton of singletons will not get you anywhere her. Set up a proper chain of dependency and delegation. Your `MSReceive` instance has **nothing** to do with your `MSSend` instance. Setting a property in one instances does not effect the other one at all.

Comment: From what I am reading,  sounds like you want to share a string between Send and Receive by having a single variable tied between the two.  Quickest way to accomplish this is by having `MessageStorage` have a class or static variable, this will allow any object to read and write to 1 variable location

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to `MessageStorage`:

```
@interface MessageStorage : NSObject
@property NSString *someProperty;
@end
```

And reference it using `self.someProperty` in the subclasses:

```
self.someProperty = @"Hello";
NSLog(@"someProperty=%@", self.someProperty);
```

If you want to reference the property from an instance of the other subclass, then you will need a reference to that class instance.  How that is achieved isn't clear from your question, so I cannot currently help with that.  The fact that both instances are derived from the same superclass is not important; the same issue will occur if the classes were not siblings.

Once you have a reference to the other class, it's simply:

```
other.someProperty = @"Hola";
```